# Как изменить регистр символа в строке используя указатель?

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Дан текст, нужно изменить регистр всех первых букв на противоположный

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *st_start;


int main()
  {
system("chcp 1251");
system("cls");

st_start=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000); //Изначально выделяем кучу памяти на  ввод строки
printf(" Введите строку: [max кол-во символов - 1000]\n ");
gets(st_start); //ввод строки

int i;
char *p;

for(p=st_start,i=1;i<=(int)strlen(st_start);p++,i++)
{
    if(p=st_start)//замена заглавной буквы
        *p=toupper(*st_start);
    if(p=' ')
        *(p+1)=toupper(*st_start);

}
puts(st_start);

return 0; }
```

Comment: Для начала, не `if (p=st_start)`, а **`if (p == st_start)`** / Далее -- `if (isalpha(...) {if (islower(...)) ... = toupper(...); else ... = tolower(...);}`  Но по хорошему, не стоит полагаться на ровно один пробел между словами, т.е. обнаружив пробел надо пропустить их все и менять уже этот символ. Кстати, при таком подходе особый случай первого символа (где сейчас ошибка) пропадет.

Comment: ну а вообще этот алгоритм правильный для того чтобы заменить первую маленькую букву слова на большую,просто у меня не работает      *(p+1)=toupper(*st_start);

Comment: Да, по крайней мере для английских букв *(не для всех символов toupper/tolower определены, вы проверьте как у вас обстоит дело с кодировкой cp-1251, просто набейте в программе один русский символ и напечатайте его перевод `printf("%c\n", toupper('я'));`)*

Comment: @avp, и ничего не получиться :) не поддерживает toupper/tolower юникод и что то отличное от ASCII, iconv надо брать, или писать таблицу символов самому, на github где то видел такую реализацию toupper/tolower.

Comment: @NewView, о каком юникоде вы говорите, если в коде ТС `system("chcp 1251");`? Как именно реализован в либах MS toupper/tolower для ANSI-кодировок -- не знаю.

Comment: @avp, ключевое слово `отличное от ASCII`, те исходники которые видел я соответствуют этому утверждению, правда там еще есть горизонт для wide символов, это для towupper/towlower, но и там они работают в рамках ASCII символов.

Comment: @NewView, пусть ТС у себя проверит (как я и посоветовал ему ранее в комментарии), если не реализовано, сделает сам.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш основной цикл содержит логические ошибки (например, в предложениях `if` вместо оператора сравнения используется оператор присваивания, или у вас не учитывается, что между ловами может быть множество пробелов).

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, в которой показано, как может быть реализована логика задания.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 1000 };
    char s[N];

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    char *p = s;

    for ( ; *p != '\n' && *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )p[0] ) && 
             ( p == s || isspace( ( unsigned char )p[-1] ) ) )
        {
            if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )p[0] ) )
            {
                p[0] = tolower( ( unsigned char )p[0] );
            }
            else
            {
                p[0] = toupper( ( unsigned char )p[0] );
            }               
        }            
    }

    *p = '\0';

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Например, если ввести строку

```
hello World!
```

то вывод программы на консоль будет выглядеть как

```
Hello world!
```